# Remove unlisted values on Symbology on ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro, legend

I have a layer file which I use as reference for symbology for future layers. It is based on unique values, however there is over 100 unique values, and each one have their own icon.

If I apply this symbology to a small layer, its legend or symbology table will have over 100 items, even if the layer only uses 3-4 symbols.

Is there a way to remove all icons that are not been used in that layer?

ArcGIS Pro has a button called Add Unlisted value, and I'm looking for the exact opposite: remove all unlisted values.

Comment: Can you share some of your arcpy code?

Comment: There is no code for that. I just use apply symbology from layer.I want to edit the result after that.

Comment: If you are not presenting code then Python should not be part of your question.  In any event, I agree with the first answerer that there appears to be a no coding solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS Pro, try checking the "Only show features visible in the map extent" box, which can be found under Feature Display Options menu. This will make it so that only things that appear in the current map extent are displayed in your legend.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/layouts/work-with-legend-items.htm

Comment: Some issues: 1- I could not find this option at all. I swear that I right-clicked everyone on map and could not find it. Sorry for the stupid question but where I find the feature display menu?
2- I will upload the layer/map to AGOL.I doubt that this solution will work when using the layer on Arcgis Online.

Answer (score 0):

In layout view, click on the legend item.  This opens the Format Legend Item area where there is an to "Only show features visible in the map extent".

Answer (score 0):

In the symbology pane on the classes tab, use the more button to show counts, then remove anything that has a 0 by right clicking and choosing remove. You can highlight multiple rows and remove them all at once.